# A basic question related to differentiability?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Was studying the continuity and differentiability,but after so many attempts to understand derivative still dont get what it really is.Let me understand this question?
I have a function say $f(x)=x^2$ and is **differentiable** at x=2 and i found its limit which came to be equal to 1 but its deivative was = 2 abd don't quite understant now what 2 gives me here.

Comment: $f'(x)=2x\Rightarrow f'(2)=4\ne 1$?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused on the geometric meaning of the derivative. Let me explain it.

**What is a derivative?**

For your function, $f(x)=x^2$, the derivative is $f^\prime(x)=2x$. However, what is the derivative? It is a measure of the rate at which the value of the function changes with respect to the change of the variable. So, since the rate of change corresponds to the slope, the derivative corresponds to the slope of the function at a point.

Hence, since you've calculated that the derivative of $f(x)=x^2$ at $x=1$ is $2$, the slope of $f(x)=x^2$ at $x=1$ is $2$.

**What is a differentiable function?**

A differentiable function is a function whose derivative exists at each point in its domain (in one variable), i.e., there is no point in the domain where a *vertical* tangent exists.

Answer (score 1):

calculating the limit
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
f'(2)&=&\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(2+h)-f(2)}{h}\\
     &=&\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{(2+h)^2-4}{h}\\
     &=&\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{4+4h+h^2-4}{h}\\
     &=&\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{h(4+h)}{h}\\
     &=&\lim\limits_{h\to 0} (4+h)\\
     &=&4+\lim\limits_{h\to 0}h=4.
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Therefore, $f'(2)=4$.